# Determining MP4 rotation in Pure Java (without native libraries)

Tags: java, android, video, metadata

I've written an Android app that (among other things) records videos, which are then uploaded to an AWS server.
On the server, I need to be able to determine the rotation of the videos. My research indicates that MP4Parser should be able to help me with that, but running:

```
    FileDataSourceImpl fileDataSource = new FileDataSourceImpl("path/to/file");
    IsoFile isoFile = new IsoFile(fileDataSource);
    MovieBox moov = isoFile.getMovieBox();
    for (Box b : moov.getBoxes()) {
        System.out.println(b);
    }
```

on my file gives me the following output:

```
MovieHeaderBox[creationTime=Wed Jun 15 12:08:38 IDT 2016;modificationTime=Wed Jun 15 12:08:38 IDT 2016;timescale=1000;duration=2057;rate=1.0;volume=1.0;matrix=Rotate 0°;nextTrackId=2]
UserDataBox[]
TrackBox[]
```

If, within my app, I run the following Android code on the *very same file*:

```
    MediaMetadataRetriever m = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
    m.setDataSource("path/to/file");
    String rotation = m.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_VIDEO_ROTATION);
    System.out.println("Rotation is " + rotation);
```

I get:

```
06-15 12:07:36.741 27424-27424/... I/System.out: Rotation is 90
```

Why the discrepancy? And is there any pure Java (no native libraries) tool that I can use to get the same results on the server side, without the benefit of the native Android code?

Thanks,
Reuven